# Java applet communication with Rails application

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, applet, jruby

I'm creating a Rails application and on it, there should be a Java Applet.

My question and problem is that the applet must be tightly integrated with the Rails parts. I must be able to get a list of all users, update an image, etc... And there's a surprisingly small amount of information available on the Internet of how to use applets with Rails. So please give me some hints. What is the best way to do it?

1. Send parameters to the applet?
2. Use Rails REST interface from the applet?
3. Use JRuby somehow?
4. Other....?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide more details?  In the meantime, here's my take on your questions:

> 1. Send parameters to the applet?

Your rails app will be able to serve the applet, but once served I don think you'll be able to send messages to it (however you will be able to respond to messages from it, which is perhaps what your asking).

> 2. Use Rails REST interface from the applet?

You've kind of answered that one yourself.  REST is an interface design and therefore can be accessed from anything that can issue a HTTP request.  The trick is to correctly construct the URL so rails knows what you want to do.  There's good info on configuring rails routes (REST and non-REST) here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

> 3. Use JRuby somehow?

You could use jruby for this, but you dont need to.  Your server (rails) and your client (browser/applet) talk to eachother via http and so don't need to be the same language or run on the same VM.

Hope that help....

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you probably haven't found anything specific about Applets and Rails is that they function a bit at different levels and aren't really dependent on one another.  It looks like Rob was trying to clarify a few things, so I'll take it another step just to be sure we are all on the same page.

The job of Rails is to generate and serve up HTML/XML/Javascript/images via a web server to the user's web browser for rendering.  Part of that HTML will be an APPLET (or possibly OBJECT) tag, which instructs the browser to load the applet.  Usually, this instructs the browser to invoke the Java Plug-in and lets it handle loading the applet.  Once loaded and running, however, even though the applet is displayed on the current web page in the browser (or maybe in another window even), it really isn't terribly aware of the web page it is sitting in.  For the most part, applets don't care about the browser or the page they are "part of".  So if an applet needs more information, or needs to ask for data, it usually will just send an HTTP request to the server it came from.  It would then parse the data and update itself.

I am assuming what you probably need is for something to be clicked or entered into the applet, and that data be used to update the web page that Rails is serving to the browser.  With an applet, you pretty much have 2 options:

1. Use the web server application to share state information
2. Use the Java-to-Javascript communication using JSObject as indicated at http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html

Honestly, option number 2 comes with so many caveats, that I would never use it unless you had complete control over browser and Java versions on all potential users' systems.  Even then, I'd be concerned of an update to something breaking it.

Basically, option number 1 leaves you with the Applet and the Javascript/HTML polling the web server (Rails) periodically to see if there are any updates or requests that they need to respond to for data exchange.  If the applet is updated by the user, it sends a message to the web server via a URL request/post and the next query (probably via an AJAX-like call) by the web page will see the new data and the web page will be updated with it.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two really great answers. I appreciate them a lot, thanks!

Reading your posts made me realize that the best choice is to use HTTP-requests to Rails REST interface. However, I see some downsides with this approach. But I don't see any better solution to it. One feature the applet should have, is to be able to browse and search in all products, which can be quite many. Sending a HTTP-request for each search will be expensive. Maybe I could solve this by loading all products when the applet starts. Then the browsing and searching would be fast. Or maybe do some nice caching. So once they are found, I don't fetch them again.

About not finding lots of information about this on the net. I see your point monceaux. But... I still think that there should be more. I mean, in my situation I would really like a Rails specific library that helped me send requests to correct urls. To bad Java is not that dynamic though. Kind of hard to do some stuff automatically, like in Ruby and Rails. Maybe I'll write a small library for this. I mean, I must write it anyway. So why not make a library of it? Some people might have use of it.